# Can I pass data using hidden fields between java and dot net web application?

Tags: java, .net, web, hidden-field

I am struggling to pass data between a Java web application and a .Net web application.
I need to pass some user details from Java to .Net (for every user). The java web application is a common user logon application.

Internet searches suggest to use either cookie or a DB table to share the session data.

Can I pass data using hidden fields between java and dot net web application ? I guess it not so simple like that.

Comment: what do you think "hidden field" means?

Answer (score 1):

If "hidden field" refers to a hidden form field, this would be possible but seems not like a reasonable solution. I also assume you are using browser as client.

There are some problems with this idea:

1. You would have to add a hidden field to every "form" sent to the .NET web app. For non-form calls (like GET queries) you would have to add the information in the URL!
2. You would need to write rather complex client logic that injects those fields to forms and/or URLs. Logic that is already available if you would use e.g. cookies.
3. Security: Everyone could tamper with the data saved in your hidden fields, probably manipulating your app's behaviour in a way you don't expect.

My recommendation:

- Use cookies if it is small data (like an authentication token)
- Use a cookie with a sesssion ID, keep all the other data in an associated database table (or session abstraction in your framework) if there is more data to share.

Answer (score 0):

Hidden field is part of HTML, but hidden field can be used with JSP. Hidden field can carry hidden data from one page to another action page. Value of hidden field can be get from request.getParameter method. Hidden field can be set from java data types e.g. String, int, float.

```
<%@ page  language="java" %>
<%
 String hiddenFieldValue="MyHiddenValue";
%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hidden fields in JSP</title>
</head>

<body>
<form name="frm" action="page2.jsp">

<input type="hidden" name="hdField" value="<%=hiddenFieldValue%>" />

<input type="text" name="txtField" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

get value of hidden field in page2.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" %>
<%
 String getHiddenValue=request.getParameter("hdField");
 System.out.println("Hidden field Value :"+getHiddenValue);
%>
```

Output

```
Hidden field Value :MyHiddenValue
```

Comment: Thanks Kannan. But my problem is to transfer data cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

You can send information to the .net  web application thru the URL using a QueryString.

```
SamplePage.aspx?info= test
```

Comment: Thanks this would work perfect. But do not want to expose the data in the URL.